# Symfony2 Behat Extending Contexts will result in "Step is already defined"

Tags: php, symfony, testing, behat, mink

I am trying to write some Behat tests for an application and I need to separate the Contexts so I can use some core elements in different other contexts for example the logged in user step.

> behat.yml

```
suites:
    common:
        type: symfony_bundle
        bundle: CommonBundle
        mink_session: symfony2
        mink_javascript_session: selenium2
        autoload:
            'CommonContext': %paths.base%/src/xxx/CommonBundle/Features/Context
        contexts: [ xxx\CommonBundle\Features\Context\CoreContext ]

    user:
        type: symfony_bundle
        bundle: UserBundle
        mink_session: symfony2
        mink_javascript_session: selenium2
        autoload:
            'UserContext': %paths.base%/src/xxx/UserBundle/Features/Context
        contexts:
            - Behat\MinkExtension\Context\MinkContext
            - xxx\CommonBundle\Features\Context\CoreContext
            - xxx\UserBundle\Features\Context\UserContext
```

> DefaultContext.php

```
namespace XXX\CommonBundle\Features\Context;

use ...

/**
 * Class DefaultContext
 */
class DefaultContext extends MinkContext implements Context, KernelAwareContext
{

    /**
     * @param AbstractEntity $oEntity
     *
     * @return object
     */
    protected function getRepository(AbstractEntity $oEntity)
    {
        return $this->getService($oEntity);
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    protected function getEntityManager()
    {
        return $this->getService('doctrine')->getManager();
    }

    /**
     * @param $id
     *
     * @return object
     */
    protected function getService($id)
    {
        return $this->getContainer()->get($id);
    }
```

> CoreContext.php

```
namespace XXX\CommonBundle\Features\Context;

use ...

/**
 * Class SubContext
 */
class CoreContext extends DefaultContext implements Context, SnippetAcceptingContext
{

    /**
     * @Given I visit the homepage
     * @When I visit the homepage
     */
    public function iVisitHomepage()
    {
        $this->visitPath('/');
    }

    /**
     * @And /^I am logged in as "([^"]*)"$/
     * @Then /^I am logged in as "([^"]*)"$/
     */
    public function iAmLoggedInAs($username)
    {
        $user = $this->getContainer()->get('fos_user.user_manager')->findUserByUsername($username);

        $this->visit('/login');

        $this->fillField('_username', $user->getEmailCanonical());
        $this->fillField('_password', self::USER_PASSWORD);

        $this->pressButton('_submit');
    }
```

> UserContext.php

```
namespace xxx\UserBundle\Features\Context;

use ...

/**
 * Defines application features from the specific context.
 */
class UserContext extends CoreContext implements Context, SnippetAcceptingContext
{

    /**
     * Initializes context.
     *
     * Every scenario gets its own context instance.
     * You can also pass arbitrary arguments to the
     * context constructor through behat.yml.
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
    }

}
```

> register_user.feature

```
Feature: Register user

  @javascript
  Scenario: Register user
    Given I am on homepage
    And I go to "/register/"
    And I am logged in as "foo@bar.com"
    Then I should see "Terms and Conditions"
```

So when I run the test I get an error saying this:

```
Given I am on homepage
      Step "I visit the homepage" is already defined in xxx\CommonBundle\Features\Context\CoreContext::iVisitHomepage()

      xxx\CommonBundle\Features\Context\CoreContext::iVisitHomepage()
      xxx\CommonBundle\Features\Context\CoreContext::iVisitHomepage()
    And I go to "/register/"
      Step "I visit the homepage" is already defined in xxx\CommonBundle\Features\Context\CoreContext::iVisitHomepage()

      xxx\CommonBundle\Features\Context\CoreContext::iVisitHomepage()
      xxx\CommonBundle\Features\Context\CoreContext::iVisitHomepage()
```

Do i understood this completely wrong or I am missing some settings here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Do not extend contexts that provide step definitions.** There's no way around this.

Good extensions provide contexts with handy methods but no step definitions. In case of the Mink extension, next to the `MinkContext` you also have `RawMinkContext`. First provides step definitions and should not be extended. The other one provides helper methods you might be interested in. The `RawMinkContext` is the one you should extend. Alternatively you can also use the `MinkAwareTrait`.

Comment: Ok but if i use more contexts as array inside behat.yml then it still return the same error. If you see what i did in user suite. That has to do with the same logic?

Comment: You won't get the error unless you include the same context multiple times, or one of your contexts extends a context that contains steps. Both of your contexts extend the CoreContext which extends the MinkContext (through the DefaultContext). MinkContext contains step definitions and should NOT be extended.

Comment: In my experience it's worth to keep the inheritance layers simple and I hardly extend other contexts. Helper methods like your `getRepository()` can be included with traits.

Comment: Yes you are right with the traits. I think it makes sense what you say. Will try it out. Hopefully it works!

Answer (score 0):

There has been a shift on what Contexts where in Behat2 and what they are now in Behat3. Contexts in Behat3 are more about "situations" in which your tests might occur. For instance:

- Logged in
- Anonymous visitor
- Public API call
- Authenticated API call
- Disabled javascript browser
- Enabled javascript browser

And so on.

So I'm afraid that the problem is in your configuration of the CoreContext being used in two suites. You can try to avoid this by running your suites separately so it does not load both configurations (and it does not autoload twice the same Context) or to change the Context strategy to not use the autoload, but something different like encapsulating common step logics into their own classes that are then being used from different Contexts.

Hope it helps